# What are the characteristics of the Meraki SpeedBurst traffic shaping algorithm?

Tags: wifi, traffic-shaping, meraki

I've been using [Cisco Meraki](https://meraki.cisco.com) wireless access points to provide guest and [BYOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_your_own_device) access at some of my customer sites. One of the interesting bandwidth management features is the [SpeedBurst](https://meraki.cisco.com/blog/2010/06/speedburst-faster-browsing-for-guest-networks/) traffic shaping option.

This is described simply as a temporary suspension of the bandwidth limit to make access feel *"snappier"*, followed by a throttling down to the fixed limit.

[image]

While giving a demo of a BYOD network for a client, I was asked how the SpeedBurst option worked, and didn't really have a good answer.

I'm curious about the specifics of this feature.

- Is the algorithm described in detail anywhere?
- How long is traffic *burstable*?
- What do repeated requests from the connected client look like and how does that impact overall speed and experience?

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your question, but it's likely some sort of Token Bucket shaper.

Comment: Have you tried asking Meraki through their support channel or your sales rep?  I've found they can be quite responsive to this kind of question.

Comment: Nah... didn't want to take the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.meraki.com/display/MX/Traffic+shaping+settings

> Enable SpeedBurst: To provide a better user experience in bandwidth-limited environments, an administrator can enable SpeedBurst by selecting the Enable Speedburst checkbox. SpeedBurst allows users to exceed their assigned limit in a "burst" for a short period of time, providing a more satisfying Internet browsing experience while still preventing any one user from using more than his or her fair share of bandwidth over the longer term. Users are allowed up to four times their allotted bandwidth limit for a period of up to five seconds.